# Linking iOS app store custom landing page to a Facebook ad campaign

Tags: app-store, facebook-ads

Recently Apple introduced a custom product page feature where multiple different App landing pages can be made.

While running Facebook ads, there is no option to link an ad set to a particular landing page’s Url. It only detects the app and sends to main listing.

Any experience with this?

Can any 3rd party service like Appsflyer help in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no chance to do it because Facebook didn't give such an opportunity even with deep links. Only web2app solutions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).